# How to display JSON values from API

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to display this API content e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(data.Title)
```

which would display

```
"Lembethe leading by example"
```

Have a look at my code

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"url");
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(data.Title);
}
```

These are my Classes below 1

```
public partial class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_tags")]
    public List<string> CustomTags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("blurb")]
    public string Blurb { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("published_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset PublishedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thumbnail")]
    public Banner Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("banner")]
    public Banner Banner { get; set; }
}
```

These are my Classes below 2

```
public partial class Banner
{
    [JsonProperty("small")]
    public string Small { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("medium")]
    public string Medium { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("large")]
    public string Large { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original")]
    public string Original { get; set; }
}
```

where did I go wrong it does't even give me an error or output?

Comment: The data for `Result` is under the `result` property, so you are missing a root class: `public class SomeName{ public Result Result { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of JSON data format `result` is an array, you can try this sample to make it.

- You can use [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
- If you can't use  [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) you can instead http://json2csharp.com/ online JSON to `Model` class.

`Model` Look like this.

```
public class Tag
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public bool subscribed { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public object small { get; set; }
    public object medium { get; set; }
    public object large { get; set; }
    public object original { get; set; }
}

public class Banner
{
    public string small { get; set; }
    public string medium { get; set; }
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string original { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
    public List<string> custom_tags { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string blurb { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public DateTime published_at { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public Banner banner { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public DateTime first { get; set; }
    public DateTime last { get; set; }
}

var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https:....");
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
 Console.WriteLine(data.result[0].title);
```

Comment: You are a GOD, Thanks alot...I'm on Mac...what can I use as an alternative to  Web Essentials? for MacOS

Comment: Hi @Komicon I would suggest you create another thread for this question, because of it is another question.

Comment: I did but no Helped it's been 4 days now

Answer (score 0):

Because You used wrong Parsing models you can use [Model generator](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp)

Use this code with below models

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

> Side note:- prefer using HttpClient instead of WebClient, [Here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient) is Good Example for that

**Models:-**

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first")]
    public DateTimeOffset First { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last")]
    public DateTimeOffset Last { get; set; }
}

public partial class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_tags")]
    public List<string> CustomTags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("blurb")]
    public string Blurb { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("published_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset PublishedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("thumbnail")]
    public Banner Thumbnail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("banner")]
    public Banner Banner { get; set; }
}

public partial class Banner
{
    [JsonProperty("small")]
    public string Small { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("medium")]
    public string Medium { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("large")]
    public string Large { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original")]
    public string Original { get; set; }
}

public partial class Tag
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subscribed")]
    public bool Subscribed { get; set; }
}
```